# How to increase Heap and Perm memory in Jboss?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jboss

The real problem is that I don´t know how to increase the Perm size memory base on my RAM memory available on my server.
 I'm in the config file and I can see that I have reserved for the heap memory 8192Mb and MaxPermSize as 1024m.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

The total memory available on my server is 9Gb. As far as I know, the Perm memory space doesn´t belong to the heap memory. I'm using 8Gb for the Heap memory and 1Gb for the Perm.
So, if I want to increase the Perm Memory I will need to reduce the Heap memory, for example to 7GB and then increase the Perm Memory to 2GB, right?
Or I can leave 8Gb for the heap memory and also increase to 2Gb the PermSize.

I'm doing this because I received this error from my server. But I´m not sure what is the problem, because as you can see the Eden space is full but also the PermGen is full.
But the problem can be in the configuration if I have 9GB ram memory available on my server and I have 8Gb reserved for the heap memory and 1 for the perm memory, probably the memory reserved for one space is not fully taken.

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 1937408K, used 1119744K [0x0000000755500000, 0x00000007ff680000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1119744K, 100% used [0x0000000755500000,0x0000000799a80000,0x0000000799a80000)
  from space 817664K, 0% used [0x0000000799a80000,0x0000000799a80000,0x00000007cb900000)
  to   space 811008K, 0% used [0x00000007cde80000,0x00000007cde80000,0x00000007ff680000)
 ParOldGen       total 5592064K, used 5591839K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000755500000, 0x0000000755500000)
  object space 5592064K, 99% used [0x0000000600000000,0x00000007554c7ce0,0x0000000755500000)
 PSPermGen       total 261120K, used 260769K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000005cff00000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 261120K, 99% used [0x00000005c0000000,0x00000005cfea86c8,0x00000005cff00000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have MaxPermSize=1024m but PSPermGen allocated only 261m, so you don't use all.

Setting Xms differently from Xmx ist usually not good from a performance point of view.

You use all of your physical memory for Heap and PermGen. You should keep some of the memory for the OS. Your server might begin to page.

It might be helpful to analyse the gc-log or use jstat, jconsole or jvisualvm to monitor your memory usage.

Comment: You said that I don´t use all my perm Memory but the log says that it is 99% used. Why do I only have 261 PSPermGen if I have it configured to use 1Gb. How can I change that?

Comment: The maximum size is 1024m but the currently allocated size for the permanent generation is 261m. The JVM doesn't need more, so it doesn't allocate more. You could set -XX:PermSize to increase the initial size, but if you don't need the space why allocating much more than needed from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks Erhard for your answers. I have another one. If the memory is at 99% why the JVM doesn´t allocate more memory? On the other hand with the information you gave me, I can deduce that I don´t need to increase the PermSizeMax memory and what I need is to increase the Heap Memory. Although what I really need is to find the application that consumes that much memory, I will fix that later.